# Rotate model to face direction it's traveling in 3d with scenekit and swift - Boids implementation

Tags: 3d, quaternion

I am implementing a boids simulation using Swift and Scenekit. Implementing the simulation itself has been fairly straight forward however I have been unable to make my models faces the direction they are flying (at least all the time and correctly) To see the full project, you can get it here (https://github.com/kingreza/Swift-Boids)

Here is a link to a video that shows the behavior I'm getting right now:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9k07wxod3yI

Here is what I am doing to rotate the models to face the direction they are going:

```
func rotateShipToFaceForward(ship: Ship, positionToBe: SCNVector3)
  {
    var source = (ship.node.position - ship.velocity).normalized();

    // positionToBe is ship.node.position + ship.velocity which is assigned to ship.position at the end of this call
    var destination = (positionToBe - ship.node.position).normalized();

    var dot = source.dot(destination)

    var rotAngle = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(acos(dot));
    var rotAxis = source.cross(destination);

    rotAxis.normalize();

    var q = GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndAxis(Float(rotAngle), Float(rotAxis.x), Float(rotAxis.y), Float(rotAxis.z))

    ship.node.rotation = SCNVector4(x: CGFloat(q.x), y: CGFloat(q.y), z: CGFloat(q.z), w: CGFloat(q.w))


}
```

Comment: What is the behaviour you're getting with your current implementation?

Comment: https://youtu.be/9k07wxod3yI @AlexandreVaillancourt

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I think the model's are not rotating on their y axis. ( they don't face the direction they are going if it's toward or away from the camera)

Comment: What you could add in there to help debug is a "[3d gizmo](http://www.3dmax-tutorials.com/graphics/ico_move_gizmo_centerbox.gif)" for the model and for the heading. This sometimes help to see discrepancies between what there is and what is expected.

Comment: It looks like you're assigning a quaternion value to a rotation matrix property. My understanding is that they're two completely different representations of rotation. This could be your issue. You want to assign ship.node.orientation = q.